# How to build OpenSSL under Emscripten in Windows?

Tags: openssl, emscripten

For windows, too, I do not understand how to build. I do so, but get an error

```
perl Configure VC-WIN32 
nmake
```

NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'rc' : return code '0x1'

But it's not terrible - I found lib under Windows.

OpenSSL sources are a hell of a mix of C and Perl. And as I understand it, you first need to configure them with perl for the desired compiler, and then build them.

Here's a great advice:  [How to link OpenSSL with emscripten?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45974738/how-to-link-openssl-with-emscripten) "Compile the two libraries : crypto and openssl with emscripten" Good idea, but how do I do that?

Here is a similar question, but this is how I understood it under unix: [Linking OpenSSL with webassembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52327290/linking-openssl-with-webassembly)

Maybe there is a ready-made library somewhere? Will this library built in unix for windows work?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this link will be helpful.
https://asyncoder.com/2020/01/02/Mac%E4%B8%8A%E7%BC%96%E8%AF%91openSSL%E5%88%B0WebAssembly/

if you follow what it said you can get libcrypto.a and libssl.a. They can be used in windows and unix and mac. But I found some functions not working...

Comment: As links can change and/or go down, it is usually best to at least outline or include the full answer within your reply.